# Can I use "if" in PyCharm for a word?

Tags: if-statement, input, pycharm, int, valueerror

i'm pretty new in using Python and PyCharm so I'm looking for a little help here. Maybe this question can sound stupid for you, but trust me I'll be very happy for every answer I got here.

This is my code in PyCharm. I wanna make something like the Mad Libs program (is that really a name of it?) and I'm currently trying to find a way where program can figure out favourite color of User, haha. I copied the procedure which is working with numbers, but looks like words are very different.

[error screenshot over here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BkTB.jpg)

Hopefully you can understand my weak english and my funny problem.

Thank you so much!
 - Alice <3

Comment: Hi, the problem in your code is that you cast `input()` return value to integer, but from your console you input string (color name). You can avoid this error by removing `int()` from `int(input())`

Please, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is on the following line:

```
answer2 = int(input("My best color is "))
```

You are trying to *cast* the user input to integer. This means that you are trying to 'convert' a string like purple in a number. 
This raised the error that you can see in the console.

In order to fix it, you can use the following command instead:

```
answer2 = input("My best color is ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Giordano! That helped, I also had to change:

`if answer2 != fav_color:`
to 
`if answer2 == fav_color:`

Comment: Yes, but it does not depend on the input type (string or int), it is for both